# System.Diagnostics.Process.Start() opens/runs wrong directory?

Tags: c#, .net, process.start

I think I found a bug. In my opinion Process.Start runs wrong directory.
To test, create default console application template and paste following:

---

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool test = false;

            DirectoryInfo root = Directory.CreateDirectory(
                System.IO.Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "folder"));

            DirectoryInfo bug = Directory.CreateDirectory(
                System.IO.Path.Combine(root.FullName, "bug"));
            DirectoryInfo bugDotCom = Directory.CreateDirectory(
                System.IO.Path.Combine(root.FullName, "bug.com"));

            ProcessStartInfo bugPSI = new ProcessStartInfo(bug.FullName);
            ProcessStartInfo bugDotComPSI = new ProcessStartInfo(bugDotCom.FullName);

            if (test)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(bug.FullName);
                Process.Start(bugPSI);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(bugDotCom.FullName);
                Process.Start(bugDotComPSI);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

---

when variable **test** is set to false, **bug.com** directory should be opened, otherwise **bug** directory. However, this example shows that always **bug.com** is opened (no matter to **test** variable) - at least for me.
What's wrong? I'm missing something or that's just a bug?

Comment: What happens if you change `com` to `Random`?  **EDIT**: It works if there is no `bug.com`.

Comment: +1 that looks like a bug.  Explorer should not use PATHEXT here.  You may want to report it using Connect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.com` is part of `%PATHEXT%`, so Windows will use it if it exists.

Changing the extension so that there is no `bug.com` folder avoids the problem.

To fix the problem, add a `\` to the end of the path.